# Half-Duplex Communications Over Serial Connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, rs485

I'm trying to setup an interface between two devices without losing data due to bit errors. Currently, I have two raspberry pi's which are each connected to a USB/RS485 converter. The two converter's are connected with a 3-wire cable, TX/RX/GND.

Because it is half duplex, if I write to either of the /dev/ttyUSB0 serial ports at the same time, it will cause bit errors. What is the best way to setup this system to avoid this issue?
[image]

Comment: You'll need to define a master/slave protocol.  One end needs to be the slave and can only transmit when the other end tells it to.

Comment: "*a 3-wire cable, TX/RX/GND*" -- If actually wired this way, then you wouldn't need to run half-duplex. RS-485 uses *differential* signals, typically labeled `A` and `B`.  "*if I write to ...*" -- You need to remove yourself from the picture. Once you get more involved with one simple routine/component, this "*I*" could refer to more than one specific component. The use of any pronoun (e.g. "*I*" or "*it*") is usually ambiguous. Use proper nouns, and be specific and clear. "*it will cause bit errors*" -- "*Bit errors*" can have many causes. But your concern is actually *collisions*.

Comment: What is involved in defining a master/slave protocol? Should I be sending ENQ "\x05" to query messages from the master to the slave? and ACK "\x06" to acknowledge them? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: One unit is designated the Master, the other unit(s) is/are the slaves. Slaves always start out in listening mode. A slave only transmits its `response` after it receives a `request` message (from the Master). The response must be completed in a timely manner; otherwise the Master assumes no response, and takes control of the serial link. It's the `request`/`response` dialog that establishes the hierarchy. The composition of the messages (and use of ASCII control codes) is whatever you want/need. Suggest you use CRC checkwords for each message to validate integrity and detect "*bit errors*".